# Attach file in email

Tags: android

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

        String fname1 = text_fname.getText().toString();
        String fname2 = edit_fname.getText().toString();

        String lname1 = text_lname.getText().toString();
        String lname2 = edit_lname.getText().toString();    

        String space = "\t";
        String newLine = "\n";

        File file = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            file = getActivity().getFilesDir();
            fos = getActivity().openFileOutput("test.xls", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(fname1.getBytes());
            fos.write(space.getBytes());
            fos.write(fname2.getBytes());
            fos.write(newLine.getBytes());
            fos.write(lname1.getBytes());
            fos.write(space.getBytes());
            fos.write(lname2.getBytes());
            fos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (fos!=null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File saved in " + file, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body of email");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    }
```

On the click of the button, I'm creating a "test.xls" file with strings inside and also calling this:

[image]

Here's the output after clicking gmail:

[image]

My questions is, how can I attach "test.xls" file in my email? So i can send it to whoever recipient I'd like.

Comment: take a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/folderName/test.xls");
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        String to[] = { email };
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."),
                1222);
```

Comment: What do you mean by /folderName/? You mean the data/data/packagename/files?

Comment: It says "Can not add this attachment"

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your `Intent`.

```
String PATH="Full path of the File that you want to send" ;
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(PATH));
```

Comment: How can I know the path?

Comment: @user3173245: if `file` is the name of the `File` that you want to attach then `file.getAbsolutePath()` will return the path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
                "mail-id" });
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/folder_name/file_name"));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: It says "Can not add this attachment"

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, in your project create **EmailActivity.java** class and paste this code..

```
package com.app.yourpackegename;

import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

public class EmailActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //  to send data.xls stored in Root of SDCARD 
        // Environment.getExternalStorageState() returns location of sdcard

        String fullFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageState()+ "/data.xls"; 
        String email = "you@yourdomain,com";
        String subject = "email subject";
        String message = "custome message string";

        File file = new File(fullFilePath);
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        String to[] = { email };
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);

        int requestCode = 1000;

        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail via..."), requestCode);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you. let me know :)